# I am not able to add dependencies and error after adding englishwords in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies

```
[flutter_application_1] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_application_1...           
Error on line 31, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
   ╷
31 │ ┌     sdk: flutter
32 │ │     english_words: ^4.0.0
33 │ │ 
34 │ │ 
35 │ │   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
36 │ │   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
37 │ │   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   │ └──^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65
```

Comment: Can you include your pubspec.yaml ?

Answer (score 1):

There is indentation error , try this

```dart
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  english_words: ^4.0.0
```

dot indicates the space

[image]